# Blackberry - systemLock() not working

Tags: api, blackberry, java-me

I'm trying to use the systemLock() to lock the device when the getSpeed() returns a value greater than 20 m/s.

```
public void locationUpdated(LocationProvider provider, Location location)
        {
            if(location.isValid())
            {
                float speed = location.getSpeed();

                 // Information to be displayed on the device
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                sb.append("\n");
                sb.append("Speed : ");
                sb.append(speed);
                sb.append(" m/s");

                if(speed < 20){
                    appMan = ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager();
                    appMan.lockSystem(true);
                }else{

                }
                MyApp.this.updateLocationScreen(sb.toString());
            }

        }
```

I have a RichTextField and I can use the .settext() successfully in the if/else statement to change the RichTextField's text so I must be using the lockSystem() wrong.

**Edit**

```
if(speed > 20 || Double.isNaN(speed)){
                    requestForeground();
                    appMan = ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager();
                    appMan.lockSystem(true);
                }else{

                }
```

Comment: `lockSystem(true)` only works if a password is set on the device. To block the user from using the device, it is much more simpler to push a global screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs on [Location](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/javax/microedition/location/Location.html)

> public float getSpeed()
>   Returns:
>   the current ground speed in m/s for
>   the terminal or Float.NaN if the speed is not known

In Java, any comparison against Float.NaN will return false, so your lock screen code block won't execute if your device is returning NaN as the speed.  You might want to add `Double.isNaN(speed)` to your condition.

Comment: I made the edit shown above. The call to requestForeground() works but the lockSystem(true) still has no effect

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes to the eyes is:

> to lock the device when the getSpeed() returns a value **greater than** 20 m/s.

and

```
if (speed < 20) {
    appMan = ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager();
     appMan.lockSystem(true);
}
```

Comment: Hi yes this was a typo. Thanks. Still not locking though.

Comment: Do you test on real device OR on the simulator? I guess simulator could do a bad job simulating a locked device.

Comment: BTW, how do you check whether there is a locked state or not?

Comment: Actually I wasn't checking. The app starts automatically, then is called to the foreground. I tested on the sim and an actual device. I was going to add the check for lock later.

Comment: If you tested on real device then it should have been possible to check whether the device gets locked or not. Am I missing anything? :)

Comment: Yes I tested it and it didn't lock